# Replace string to the target format

Tags: .net, regex, vb.net, string, replace

Is there a way to replace a string using `regex` or string replace

```
COND X > 49 300000 200000
```

The expected format is

```
COND(X > 49,300000,200000)
```

My current approach is to do `string.Split(" ")` and convert it to list and insert the braces at the proper indexes. But the problem with my approach is the string is not standalone but is included in a larger expression and also sometimes the comparison happens with `whitespace` as in `COND ABC =`. The right side of the condition is a whitespace.

Comment: What .NET language are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is impossible to achieve in a single pass. I suggest:

1. Adding parentheses: `(\p{Lu}+)\s*(\p{Lu}+)(.*)` (replace with `$1($2$3)`)

See [demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%5Cp%7BLu%7D%2B)%5Cs*(%5Cp%7BLu%7D%2B)%5Cs*(.*)&i=COND%20X%20%3E%2049%20300000%20200000&r=%241(%242%243))

2. Then, you can use a regex to find all spaces between numbers and replace them with a comma: `(?<=\d+)\s+(?=\d+)`.

See [demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3f%3c%3d%5cd%2b)%5cs%2b(%3f%3d%5cd%2b)&i=COND(X+%3e+49+300000+200000)&r=%2c) (see Context tab).

Here is a working VB.NET code:

```
Dim strIn As String = "COND X > 49 300000 200000"
Dim rx2 = New Regex("(\p{Lu}+)\s*(\p{Lu}+)(.*)")
Dim result2 As String = rx2.Replace(strIn, "$1($2$3)")
result2 = Regex.Replace(result2, "(?<=\d+)\s+(?=\d+)", ",")
```

Output:

[image]

**EDIT**: 1-REGEX PASS:

If you use a `MatchEvaluator` function inside `Regex.Replace`, we can make sure we only run regex once.

```
Dim str3 = "COND X > 49 300000 200000 778888"
    Dim rx3 = New Regex("(\p{Lu}+)\s*(\p{Lu}+.*?)(?:\s+(\d+))+")
    Dim result2 = rx3.Replace(str3, New MatchEvaluator(Function(m As Match)
                        If m.Groups(3).Captures.Count > 0 Then
                             Return String.Format("{0}({1} {2})",
                                               m.Groups(1).Value,
                                               m.Groups(2).Value,
                                               String.Join(",",
                                                            m.Groups(3).Captures.Cast(Of Capture)().Select(Function(n) n.Value).ToArray()
                                                           )
                                               )
                         Else
                             Return m.Value
                         End If
                         End Function))
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Great, if you found my answer helpful, please also consider upvoting.

Answer (score 2):

Setup your capture groups in your `RegularExpression` and just stick the appropriate delimiters between the groups.

NOTE: This only works if you have 3 sets of digits you want to stick commas in between.

```
Imports System
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        Dim str As String = "COND X < 49 300000 200000"
        '^ Beginning of the line
        '([A-Z]+)\s* capture group 1 that will have any capital letters before the first space,
        '  but the space is not included in the group
        '([A-Z]\s*..?\s*) capture group 2 that will have X (or any single capital letter) plus
        '  a space, then any character plus a possible character (<=), then a space
        '(\d+)\s* capture group 3 & 4 that will have the first group of digits plus a space, but 
        '  the space is not included in the group
        '(\d+)$ capture group 5 that will have the last group of digits. $ End of line
        Dim pattern As String = "^([A-Z]+)\s*([A-Z]\s*..?\s*)(\d+)\s*(\d+)\s*(\d+)$"
        Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace(str, pattern, "$1($2$3,$4,$5)"))
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub
End Module
```

Results:

```
COND(X > 49,300000,200000)
```

### UPDATE

If you're dealing with more than three sets of digits, then using Regex.Match and building your string allows one pass through.

```
Imports System
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        Dim str As String = "COND X >= 49 300000 200000 123456 456789"
        '([A-Z]+)\s* capture group 1 that will have any capital letters before the first space,
        '  but the space is not included in the group
        '([A-Z]\s*..?\s*) capture group 2 that will have X (or any single capital letter) plus
        '  a space, then any character plus a possible character (<=), then a space
        '(.+)\s* capture group 3 that will have the sets of digits with spaces in between
        Dim pattern As String = "([A-Z]+)\s*([A-Z]\s*..?\s*)(.+)"
        Dim groups As GroupCollection = Regex.Match(str, pattern).Groups
        Console.WriteLine("{0}({1}{2})", groups(1), groups(2), groups(3).Value.Replace(" ", ","))
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub
End Module
```

Results:

```
COND(X >= 49,300000,200000,123456,456789)
```

Comment: Cool, but how do you know the amount of digit groups in the input string? What if there is 4: `123 223 3456 4567`? It is not clear from the question of course, but to be on the safer side and do not compromise performance with `\G` operator, we'd better use a 2-pass approach. However, there is one-regex approach, I will update my answer.

Comment: @stribizhev I mentioned in a note about how it would only work with 3 sets of digits.  Updated answer captures 3 groups and reconstructs the result.

Answer (score 1):

You can use following regex for detect :

```
(.*)(\w\s?>[\s\d]+)
```

and following for replace :

```
$1\($2\)
```